# How do I type a backtick (`) using the software keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

When I bring up the keyboard and press the `&123` button, I don't see the backtick character anywhere.  I have also pressed the right arrow button to see more symbols, but it's not on that screen either.  I am sure there are other missing symbols too.  Is there a way to type these in?

Comment: For questions like this, you should specify which keyboard language you're using, as the layout differs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Tap and hold on the apostrophe key, popup will appear with it on.

**Update**

Found this link with all the 'tap and hold' keys

http://www.sadev.co.za/content/windows-phone-7-professional-tips-press-and-hold